# Value of type 'Results' has no member 'latitude’

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

外部フレームワークとしましてRealmを使用し、
CLLocationから値を取得しまして

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var locations: Results<Location>!


// Make Location from CLLocation
private func makeLocation(rawLocation: CLLocation) -> Location {
    let location = Location()
    location.latitude = rawLocation.coordinate.latitude
    location.longitude = rawLocation.coordinate.longitude

    return location
```

である場合に

```
let location = locations
```

としまして

```
let valString:String = "\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)"
```

というようにStringにしたいと考えていますが、 `Value of type 'Results<Location>' has no member 'latitude'`というエラーになってしまいます。どのような解決方法がございますでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Core Locationのデータ型に`Results`と言うのはなかったはずなので、`Results`の定義がどうなっているのか、どうやってその値を取得したのかを記載してもらわないと何とも言えません。ご質問を編集して、必要な情報を追記してください。

Comment: コメントではなく質問本文を編集していただけませんか。それと`Results`も`Location`もAppleのフレームワークには含まれていません。何かサードパーティ製のフレームワーク等を使用されているなら、そちらも(Realm?)ご記載ください。また、`locations`に値を設定している部分もお願いします。

Comment: ご回答いただいたにもかかわらず、大変申し訳ありませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locations`は`Results<Location>`型のオブジェクトなので、それには`latitude`や`longitude`というプロパティはありません。
`let location = locations`はただ別の名前の変数に入れただけなので中身は変わっていません。

`latitude`や`longitude`など`Location`クラスのオブジェクトのプロパティにアクセスするには、まず`locations`から要素である`Location`型のオブジェクトを取り出す必要があります。

`Results<T>`から要素を取り出すには下記に示す方法があります。

1. Subscriptingを使う。

   ```
   let location = locations[0]
   let valString = "\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)"
   ```
2. `first`や`last`を使う

   ```
   let location = locations.first!
   let valString = "\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)"
   ```

^ 上記の`first`/`last`の戻り値はオプショナルなので必要に応じてアンラップする必要があります。

3. 要素をイテレートする

   ```
   for location in locations {
       let valString = "\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)"
   ```

上記以外にも`Results`の要素を取り出す方法はありますが、主なものはこんなところです。
より詳しくはドキュメント https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/ をご覧ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。lastを使い実行しましたところ、Simulator上では問題なく動作致しましたが、実機上では fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
と出るので、アンラップが必要ということですね。どのようにアンラップするのが効果的でしょうか宜しくお願い致します

Comment: 違います。`!`は強制アンラップなので使用すると自動的にアンラップされます。アンラップした結果`nil`だったのでクラッシュした、ということです。挙動はデバイスとシミュレータで変わらないので、データが無いのでしょう。`last`で値を取り出す前に`print(locations)`してみてください。たぶん空になってると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに空のようです。これはどのような事に失敗しているのでしょうか。そのままドロップピンを打つことが可能ではあります。しかし、ごく稀にデータが流れてくるというのは何故なのでしょうか。

Comment: さすがに分からないです。プログラムが間違っているんでしょう。どこかにプロジェクトごと共有してもらえると調べることもできますが。

Comment: Results<Location> (
 [0] Location {
  latitude = 37.785834;
  longitude = -122.406417;
  createdAt = 2016-07-28 11:41:03 +0000;
 },
現時点ではこのように見えている次第です。

Comment: それなら少なくとも１件はデータがあるのでクラッシュはしないと思いますけど。

Comment: すいません、大変ありがとうございます。基本的な中身はこの方のものが参考です。
(https://github.com/koogawa/GPSLoggerRealmSwift/blob/master/GPSLogger/ViewController.swift)

初心者でありますため皆様のご回答、毎回大変参考になる次第です。

Comment: とりあえず、どこでエラーが起こってるとか何をしたらクラッシュするとか、エラーの周辺のコードとかもっと情報がないとわからないです。

Comment: 基本的なコードは上記の通りで、１００メートルごとにドロップピンを作成することができている状態です。RealmのDBデータをそのままtext形式等で出力するような方法が不明であったためtextに追記できる形としてStringで一度出そうと考えまして上記コードstartButtonDidTapにwriteDocument()を追加し、func  writeDocument()以下に
let location = locations.last!
let valString:String = "\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)"
とし、起動後スタートボタンを実行しますとlet location = locations.last!でfatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional valueエラーとなります。

Comment: Realmにデータが保存されるのはスタートボタンを押した後、`locationManager(_:,didUpdateToLocation:,fromLocation:)`が呼ばれた時なので、単にスタートボタンを押した段階ではデータが1件もない、ということだと思いますが。

Comment: ということはwriteDocument()‌​を記述する場所がそもそも間違っているということでしょうか。どのようにいたしますと良いのでしょうか。

Comment: それはあなたがやりたいことによります。私にはそれは判断できません。単にクラッシュしないようにするのであれば、データが追加された直後、119行目の後でやればいいでしょうし、`startButtonDidTap()`のタイミングでやりたいのであれば、`if let location = locations.first { let valString = "\(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)" }`などのように、データがある時だけ処理をするなどの方法もあります。どれがいいかはあなたがどうしたいかによります。その質問に答えるなら、何をどうしたいか、ということをわかるように教えてください。

Comment: 今の所、ドロップピンと同じようにスタートボタンを実行後100メートル毎にvalStringにデータを入れ、printで表示を出来ればと思います。ドロップピンと同じlatitude、longitudeの数値を取得したいと考えております

Comment: それなら`func dropPin()`の中でやるのが一番いいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 最終的な目的としましては上記の通りtext形式で出すことなのですが、Realmに書き出すタイミングでwriteDocument()‌​で呼び出してfunc writeDocument() { のように別にするということはやはりできないのでしょうか。
直接的に処理をfunc dropPin()内に記述するの方が楽でしょうか。

Comment: 処理をメソッドに分けることと、それをどこで呼び出すかは別の話です。処理を`writeDocument()`に分けてそれを`dropPin()`で呼び出せばいいです。またはスタートボタンを押したときに処理をしたいのなら、その時点ではデータがない場合があるので、データがあるかどうかチェックして、ある時だけメソッドを呼ぶ、とします。ここまで、あまり理解できないようでしたら、入門書などを買ってSwiftの基本をもう少し学ばれたほうがいいです。